# Why am I getting this red explosion asterisk star with white exclamation point?

Tags: icons

[image: red explosion asterisk star icon]

This morning I got this icon in the top right of my screen. Neither clicking nor hovering does anything. I have no idea what it is supposed to be telling me. Ideas?

@pLumo: Silly question, I know, but why doesn't the icon itself just say that?

UPDATE: Here is the requested output:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease              
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jconti/recent-notifications/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Hit:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

$ apt list --upgradeable
Listing... Done
snapd/bionic-updates 2.45.1+18.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.1+18.04]
N: There are 3 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.

$ apt list --upgradeable -a
Listing... Done
snapd/bionic-updates 2.45.1+18.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.1+18.04]
snapd/now 2.42.1+18.04 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.45.1+18.04]
snapd/bionic-security 2.37.4+18.04.1 amd64
snapd/bionic 2.32.5+18.04 amd64
```

Comment: afaik this is the updater and it means updating repositories was not successful, please open a terminal and type `sudo apt update` and then edit  your question adding the full output of that command..

Comment: Looks all normal to me, maybe it relies on some old information. Open "Software Updater" and see if there is any error message or if after updating the repos the icon goes away-

Comment: No error message. Says I am up to date. And the icon is gone.

Comment: Great, so it was just a temporary issue with updating the repositories :-)